# sshfs robustness on weak connection

Tags: sshfs, remote-connection

sshfs is really nice but it creates me a lot of problems. In particular I don't have a very good Internet connection, it is fast, but it has a lot of latency.

Sometimes sshfs freezes my pc (fedora 18), in particular using emacs opening remote files. Sometimes when I save a remote file with emacs, or emacs does the autosave, emacs becomes frozen and I can only see "saving file...". Recently all my pc become frozen, also `control+alt+del` doesn't work. The only thing I can do is `control+alt+f1, init 3, init 5`.

Is there any option I can use with sshfs to tell him to be more robust on weak connection?

Comment: have you looked at Screen? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen    using screen, you can disconnect from your session and reconnect again without interuption, even if your link becomes unstable. not a perfect solution, but should allow you to isolate the freeze, and resume your session without loosing your place.

Comment: no, screen is different. I want to mount a remote file system on my pc and to work with my computer, with my program on remote files.